# How to integrate Atmosphere with Spring and Jersey?

Tags: spring, jersey, atmosphere

Currently I have a Jersey-Spring application with the following configuration.

```
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.company.sample.WebServiceApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.PostReplaceFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Now, I need to add some Atmosphere Comet capabilities into the scene. How can I achieve this? Atmosphere's docs explain how to integrate Atmosphere with Jersey or Atmosphere with Spring MVC (thus Spring), but how to integrate the three, Jersey+Spring+Atmosphere?

Comment: No one knows. Such a shame :-) .

Comment: Please, help someone. Maybe my question is not clear ...